# How can I distinguish between file names with and without suffix?

Tags: linux, sed, filenames, suffix

I am writing a bash shell script to output the suffixes of filenames.

In this case I use:

```
sed 's|.*\.||'
```

So the output is e.g.:

```
png
exe
c
```

But what do I do if the file name has no suffix and therefore no dot? My output should be "no suffix", but I don't know how to do this with sed.

EDIT
What I've already tried:

Directory:

```
abc.x
abc.y
abc
```

Input:

```
find . -type f | sed -E 's/^[^.]+$/no suffix/; s/.*\.//'
```

Output:

```
x
y
/abc
```

Comment: You can match a line with sed. `sed '/ pattern / { command only on pattern; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 consecutive substitutions:

```
sed -E 's/^[^.]+$/no suffix/; s/.+\.//'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the output is not quite correct yet.
If I try it this way:
`sed -E 's/[^.]/no suffix/; s/.+\.//'`
that' s the output:
`png`
`exe`
`c`
`.no suffixabc`

Do you have any idea how I could change it?

Comment: @D.Lay, I tested on sample list of files and didn't notice any issues. Post a testable file list into your question so I could try it.

Comment: If I try it exactly as you suggest, there is a dot in front of every file name without suffix. I tested the command `find . -type f | sed -E 's/^[^.]+$/no suffix/; s/.+\.//'` in a directory containing a few files.

Comment: @D.Lay, for that case - change `s/.+\.//` to `s/.*\.//`

Comment: Both result in the same output.

Comment: If this answer is not satisfactory, why is it accepted?

Comment: @tripleee It was not sufficient but helpful.

Comment: @D.Lay: In your attempt: you could just add a `+` after `[^.]` in your command, like: `find . -type f |sed -E 's/[^.]+/no suffix/; s/.+\.//'`  .If you want to remove the initial `.` as well, then one more substitution is required : `find . -type f |sed -E 's/[^.]+/no suffix/; s/.+\.// ; s,^\.,,'`

Answer (score 0):

One in awk. First some test material that was not provided:

```
$ cat foo
this.foo
that.bar
nothing
```

The awk:

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,".");print (n>1?a[n]:"no suffix")}' foo
foo
bar
no suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed '/.*\./s///;t;s/.*/no suffix/'
```

The regex matches lines with a dot. On those lines, we perform a substitution. If a substitution occurred, we are done. Otherwise, perform the other substitution.

The use of an empty regex in the substitution pattern uses the previous pattern. The `t` command branches if a substitution occurred; without an argument, we branch to the end of the script. (Otherwise, you can set a label with `:label` and branch to that with `tlabel`.)

Comment: I still get the same output as I wrote above.

Comment: Strange... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
abc.x
abc.y
abc

$ awk -F'.' '{print (NF>1 ? $NF : "no suffix")}' file
x
y
no suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same with the POSIX shell *parameter expansions* without invoking separate utilities. For example, to test whether a file contains a `'.'` you can simply use `test`, e.g.:

```
[ "$i" = "${i%.*}" ]
```

See [Posix Programmer's Manual - Shell Command Language - Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

If it tests TRUE, then no extension is present, otherwise, you can use an additional *parameter expansion* to obtain the extension itself, e.g.

```
[ "$i" = "${i%.*}" ] && echo "$i - no suffix" || echo "$i - ${i##*.}"
```

(**note:** you would need an additional test to exclude `.foo` (e.g. *dotfiles*), but that is left to you)

Wrap that in a loop and exclude directory files and you can test every file within a directory or use `read` within a loop and pipe a list of names to it. For example, looping over the files in a directory would results in:

```
...
ftlcdfil.c - c
geany-plugin_build_w_gtk+2.patch - patch
geany-plugins.spec - spec
geany.spec - spec
geany_build_w_gtk+2.patch - patch
getfl - no suffix
gtkw_save_test.txt - txt
gtkwrite-master.zip - zip
helloleap - no suffix
helloleap.c - c
jnl - no suffix
messages - no suffix
opensuse_15.0_1s_delay.svg - svg
...
```

Comment: Looks like another way to solve the problem. However, I have already found a solution. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: No problem. Put this in your hip pocket if you find yourself needing to handle this within a loop. Calling `awk` or `sed` repeatedly within a loop with a large number of iterations can greatly impact efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
/tmp> ls ab*
abc  abc.x  abc.y
/tmp> perl -e ' print /\./? "$_\n" : "no suffix\n" for(glob("ab*")) '
no suffix
abc.x
abc.y
/tmp>
```